# What does the => symbol mean in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, symbols

I'm new to Haskell and, in general, to functional programming, and I'm a bit uncomfortable with its syntax.

In the following code what does the `=>` denote? And also `(Num a, Ord a)`?

```
loop :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> (t -> t) -> t -> t
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This is a typeclass constraint; `(Num a, Ord a) => ...` means that `loop` works with any type `a` that is an instance of the `Num` and `Ord` typeclasses, corresponding to numeric types and ordered types respectively. Basically, you can think of `loop` as having the type on the right hand side of the `=>`, except that `a` is required to be an instance of `Num` and `Ord`.

You can think of typeclasses as basically similar to OOP interfaces (but they're not the same thing!) — they encapsulate a set of definitions which any instance must support, and generic code can be written using these definitions. For instance, `Num` includes numeric operations like addition and multiplication, while `Ord` includes less than, greater than, and so on.

For more information on typeclasses, see [this introduction](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses#typeclasses-101) from [*Learn You a Haskell*](http://learnyouahaskell.com/).

Answer (score 22):

`=>` separates two parts of a type signature:

- On the left, typeclass constraints
- On the right, the actual type

So you can think of `(Num a, Ord a) => a -> (t -> t) -> t -> t` as meaning "the type is `a -> (t -> t) -> t -> t` and also there must be a `Num` instance for `a` and an `Ord` instance for `a`".

For more on typeclasses see http://www.learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses

Answer (score 5):

One way to think about it is that `Ord a` and `Num a` are additional inputs to the function. They are a special kind of input though: *dictionaries*. When you use this function with a particular type `a`, there must also be *dictionaries* available for the `Ord` and `Num` operations on the type `a` as well.

Any function that makes use of a function with dictionary inputs must also have the same dictionary inputs.

```
foo :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> t
foo x = loop x someFunc someT
```

However, you do not have to explicitly pass these dictionaries around. Haskell will take care of that for you, assuming there is a dictionary available. You can create a dictionary with a *typeclass instance*.

```
instance Num MyType with
  x + y = ...
  x - y = ...
  ...
```

This creates a dictionary for the `Num` operations on `MyType`, therefore `MyType` can be used anywhere that `Num a` is a required input (assuming it satisfies the other requirements, of course).

Comment: It's worth clarifying that although we call them "dictionaries", they are _not_ hash tables, but rather records of functions. They are kind of like v-tables in object-oriented languages, except they are not attached to values.

Answer (score 3):

On the left hand side of the `=>` you declare constraints for the types that are used on the right.

In the example you give, it means that `a` is constrained to being an instance of both the `Ord` type class and the `Num` type class.