# Haskell Types in some examples

Tags: haskell, types

I'm in the process of learning Haskell and I'm a beginner.
I wish I could search this question on StackOverflow.
But honestly I'm not quite sure what to search for.

I already tried to get the answers without much success so
please bear with me. It seems this is still really low level
stuff.

So my ghci interactive session never seems to output
"primitive types" like Int for example. I don't know how
else to put it. At the moment I'm trying to follow the
tutorial on http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/getting-started.html.
Unfortunately, I can't seem to produce the same results.

For example:

```
Prelude> 5
5
Prelude> :type it
it :: Num a => a
```

I have to specifically say:

```
Prelude> let e = 5 :: Int
Prelude> e
5
Prelude> :type it
it :: Int
```

This is all very confusing to me so I hope somebody
can clear up this confusion a little bit.

**EDIT:**

On http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/getting-started.html it says: "Haskell has several numeric types. For example, a literal number such as 1 could, depending on the context in which it appears, be an integer or a floating point value. When we force ghci to evaluate the expression 3 + 2, it has to choose a type so that it can print the value, and it defaults to Integer." I can't seem to force ghci to evaluate the type.

So for example:

```
Prelude> 3 + 2
5
Prelude> :t it
it :: Num a => a
```

Where I expected "Integer" to be the correct type.

Comment: `(Bool, t, [Char], t1, [Bool])` can't make sense to you if you do not understand the first part. If it actually makes sense to you, what are `t` and `t2`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142731/what-does-the-symbol-mean-in-haskell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of things going on here.

1. Numeric literals in Haskell are polymorphic; the type of the literal `5` really is `Num a => a`.  It can belong to any type that adheres to the `Num` type class.
2. Addition is part of the `Num` type class, so an addition of two numeric literals is still `Num a => a`.
3. Interactive evaluation in ghci is very similar to evaluating actions in the IO monad. When you enter a bare expression, ghci acts as if you ran something like the following:

   ```
   main = do
     let it = 5 + 5
     print it
   ```

   It's not *exactly* like that, though, because in a program like that, inference would work over the entire `do` expression body to find a specific type. When you enter a single line, it has to infer a type and compile something with only the context available as of the end of the line you entered. So the `print` doesn't affect the type inferred for the let-binding, as it's not something *you* entered.
4. There's nothing in that program that would constrain `it` to a particular instance of `Num` or `Show`; this means that `it` is still a polymorphic value. Specifically, GHC compiles values with type class constraints to functions that accept a type class dictionary that provides the instance implementations required to meet the constraint. So, although `it` looks like a monomorphic value, it is actually *represented* by GHC as a function. This was surprising to enough people that the dreaded "Monomorphism Restriction" was invented to prevent this kind of surprise. It disallows pattern bindings (such as this one) where an identifier is bound to a polymorphic type.

   The Monomorphism Restriction is off by default in GHC now, and it has been off by default in GHCi since version 7.8.

   See [the GHC manual](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#idp46760125930848) for more info.
5. Haskell provides a special bit of magic for polymorphic numbers; each module can make a *default declaration* that provides type defaulting rules for polymorphic numbers. At your ghci prompt, the defaulting rules made ghci choose 'Int' when it was forced to provide instance dictionaries to `show it` in order to get to an IO action value.

   Here's the relevant section in the [Haskell 98 Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.3.4).

To sum it up: `it` was bound to the expression `5 + 5`, which has type `Num a => a` because that's the more general inferred type based on the polymorphic numeric literals.

Polymorphic values are represented as functions waiting for a typeclass dictionary. So evaluating `it` at a particular instance doesn't force it to become monomorphic.

However, Haskell's type default rules allow it to pick a particular type when you implicitly `print it` as part of the ghci interaction. It picks `Int` and so it chooses the `Int` type class instance dictionaries for `Show` and `Num` when forced to by `print it`.

I hope that makes it somewhat less confusing!

By the way, here is an example of how you can get the same behavior outside of ghci by explicitly requesting the polymorphic let-binding. Without the type signature in this context, it will infer a monomorphic type for `foo` and give a type error.

```
main = do
  let foo :: Num a => a
      foo = 5 + 5
  let bar = 8 :: Double
  let baz = 9 :: Int

  print (foo + bar)
  print (foo + baz)
```

This will compile and run, printing the following:

```
18.0
19
```

**UPDATE:**

Looking at the Real World Haskell example and the comment thread, some people included different ghci logs along with their ghc versions. Using that information, I looked at ghc release notes and found that starting in version 7.8, the Monomorphism Restriction was disabled in ghci by default.

If you run the following command, you'll re-enable the Monomorphism Restriction and in order to be friendly, ghci will default the binding to Integer rather than giving you either an error or a polymorphic binding:

```
Prelude> :set -XMonomorphismRestriction
Prelude> 5 + 5
10
Prelude> :t it
it :: Integer
Prelude>
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears that GHCi is performing some magic here. It is correctly defaulting the numbers to `Integer`s so that they can be printed. However it is binding `it` to the polymorphic type before the defaulting appears.

I guess you want to see the type after the defaulting takes place. For that, I would recommend to use the `Data.Typeable` library as follows:

```
> import Data.Typeable
> let withType x = (x, typeOf x)
> withType 5
(5,Integer)
```

Above, GHCi has to default `5` to `Integer`, but this causes `typeOf x` to report the representation of the type after the defaulting happened. Hence we get the wanted type.

The following also works, precisely because `typeOf` is called after the defaulting happened:

```
> :type 5
5 :: Num a => a
> typeOf 5
Integer
```

Keep however in mind that `typeOf` only works for monomorphic types. In general, the polymorphic result of `:type` is more useful.

Comment: I assume that this is because of the static typing, since it wouldn't be possible to do arithmetics with floats and integers making it a hassle. Can anybody second that or am I imagining things?

Comment: @Nimi Roughly, yes. Numeric _literals_ are polymorphic, so their type adapts to what's needed in the context. However, once the type is fixed, there are no implicit type conversions, e.g `Int`s are not promoted to `Double`s as in some other languages. So, the thumb rule is: no implicit conversions, but literals fit any numeric type.

Answer (score 0):

Numbers in Haskell are polymorphic, there are separate types for Fixed and arbitrary precision Integers, Rationals, Floating Point numbers, and user defined number types.  All can be instantiated with simple literals, by implementing the `fromInteger` method on the `Num` typeclass.  The value you've given, `(True, 1, "hello world", 3)` has two integral literals, and they can be used to create two numbers, of possibly different types.  the bit of type before the fat arrow, `(Num t, Num t1)`, is saying that in the inferred type, `t` and `t1` can be anything, so long as they happen to have the `Num` typeclass defined on them, ie they can be obtained with a `fromInteger`.

Comment: So does that mean that the 5 that I've been producing on the last part of my question actually has a different type for the given examples?